# Add Fing like/Network Scanning to Application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have seen a lot of questions related to obtaining a list of devices on the network and i'm not sure any of them meet my needs.  I need to be able to show a list of devices connected to the network, with IP address/Mac address.  I've seen ARP cache mentioned, as well as scanning a subnet mask, and ICMP broadcast.  Which of these is the best way to get this functionality?  I have concerns about some of the solutions I have seen posted, as most mention non-public API's it would seem.  A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, I am also not highly familiar with straight C, which a lot of the mentioned solutions use.

Comment: Have you got the solution that how can we get the details of connected devices with the wifi router in iPhone?